# How can I Post parameter in httpClient where in Postman use param

Tags: c#, web-services, dotnet-httpclient

I want to post my parameter with HttpClient.
What is the Content in httpclient request body? I wrote it int the body part  and when I run the project I get error:

[image]

My code is:

```
string baseAddress = "https://WebServiceAddress";
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
HttpRequestMessage bodyRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, baseAddress)

bodyRequest.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Prescriptionrequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var responseApi = Client.PostAsync(baseAddress, bodyRequest.Content, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(false));
```

what should be the format of `bodyRequest.Content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{    
    { "parameter0", "value0" },    
    { "parameter1", "value1" }
};    
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary);    
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://WebServiceAddress", content);    
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```